# Slow MySQL Query - GROUP BY / ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, magento

On one of my Magento shops there is a module installed, nostress export. This module fires the following MySQL query to create a product export:

```
SELECT  `cpf5`.`entity_id` AS `id`, 
        `cpf5`.`type_id` AS `product_type`, 
        CONCAT('http://www.store.com/',IFNULL(cpf5.url_path,CONCAT(cpf5.url_key,'.html'))) AS `url`,
        `cpf5`.`name`, 
        IF( cpf5.image = 'no_selection','',CONCAT('http://www.store.com/media/','catalog/product', cpf5.image)) AS `image`,
        `cpf5`.`ean`, 
        `cpf5`.`manufacturer_value` AS `manufacturer`, 
        `cpf5`.`sku`, 
        `cpf5`.`description`, 
        `cpf5`.`color_value` AS `color`, 
        `cpf5`.`new_materiaal`, 
        `cpf5`.`beslist_cat`, 
        IFNULL(cpr.parent_id,cpf5.entity_id) AS `group_id`, 
        (cpr.parent_id IS NOT NULL) AS `is_child`, 
        `ncec`.`path` AS `taxonomy_path`, 
        IF(cisi.qty > 0 OR (cisi.use_config_manage_stock = '0' AND cisi.manage_stock = '0' ),1,0) AS `stock_status`, 
        `ncmg`.`media_gallery`, 
        ROUND(cip.min_price,2) AS `price_final_include_tax`, 
        ROUND(cip.price,2) AS `price_original_include_tax` 

FROM `catalog_product_flat_5` AS `cpf5`

LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_relation` AS `cpr` ON cpr.child_id=cpf5.entity_id 
INNER JOIN `nostress_export_categoryproducts` AS `ncp` ON ncp.product_id=cpf5.entity_id OR ncp.product_id=cpr.parent_id
LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_flat_store_5` AS `ccf5` ON ccf5.entity_id=ncp.category_id
LEFT JOIN `nostress_export_cache_categorypath` AS `nccp` ON nccp.category_id =ccf5.entity_id AND nccp.store_id =5
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  `ncp`.`product_id`, MAX(ccf5.level) AS `max_level` FROM `nostress_export_categoryproducts` AS `ncp` LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_flat_store_5` AS `ccf5` ON ccf5.entity_id=ncp.category_id AND ncp.export_id = 2 WHERE (ccf5.is_active='1') GROUP BY `product_id`
) AS `ncpml` ON ncpml.max_level = ccf5.level AND (ncpml.product_id = cpf5.entity_id OR ncpml.product_id = cpr.parent_id)
LEFT JOIN `nostress_export_cache_enginecategory` AS `ncec` ON ncec.hash = ccf5.nsc_taxonomy_beslist AND locale = 'all' AND taxonomy_code ='beslist'
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_flat_5` AS `pcpf` ON pcpf.entity_id=cpr.parent_id
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `ciss` ON ciss.product_id=cpf5.entity_id AND ciss.website_id =30 
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `cisi` ON cisi.product_id=cpf5.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN `nostress_export_cache_mediagallery` AS `ncmg` ON ncmg.product_id =cpf5.entity_id AND ncmg.store_id = 5
LEFT JOIN `nostress_export_cache_tax` AS `nct` ON nct.tax_class_id = cpf5.tax_class_id AND nct.store_id = 5
LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `cip` ON cip.entity_id = cpf5.entity_id AND cip.website_id = 30 AND cip.customer_group_id = '0'

WHERE (ncp.export_id='2') AND (cpf5.type_id IN ('simple')) AND (cpf5.visibility IN('4') OR pcpf.visibility  IN('4')) GROUP BY `cpf5`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `group_id` ASC, `cpf5`.`type_id` ASC LIMIT 1000;
```

The problem is that this query takes more than 6 minutes to execute and locks the "cataloginventory_stock_status" table so all query's in that 6 minute window that need this table are getting timeouts. I narrowed it down to the last part:

```
GROUP BY `cpf5`.`entity_id` ORDER BY `group_id` ASC
```

Without it it runs in like 30 seconds. The "entity_id" has an INDEX. When I watch the MySQL processlist the query state is "Creating sort index". Is there any way to speed up this query?

If I run EXPLAIN this is the output:

```html
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                            | key                                                 | key_len | ref                                    | rows  | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ncp        | ref    | export_id,category_id,product_id                                                                                                                         | export_id                                           | 4       | const                                  | 25002 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ccf5       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_5_LEVEL                                                                                                          | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | mage.ncp.category_id            |     1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | nccp       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                                             | 6       | mage.ncp.category_id,const      |     1 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ncec       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                                     | NULL                                                | NULL    | NULL                                   |     1 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cpf5       | ref    | PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_5_TYPE_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_5_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_5_NAME,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_5_PRICE  | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_FLAT_5_TYPE_ID                  | 98      | const                                  |  7245 | Using index condition                              |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cpr        | ref    | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_RELATION_CHILD_ID                                                                                                                    | IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_RELATION_CHILD_ID               | 4       | mage.cpf5.entity_id             |     1 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | pcpf       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | mage.cpr.parent_id              |     1 | Using where                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ciss       | ref    | PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_STATUS_WEBSITE_ID                                                                                                     | IDX_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_STATUS_WEBSITE_ID        | 6       | const,mage.cpf5.entity_id       |     3 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cisi       | ref    | UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID,IDX_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID                                                           | UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID | 4       | mage.cpf5.entity_id             |     1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | ncmg       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                                             | 6       | mage.cpf5.entity_id,const       |     1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | nct        | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | mage.cpf5.tax_class_id,const    |     1 | Using where; Using index                           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | cip        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID,IDX_CATALOG_PRODUCT_INDEX_PRICE_WEBSITE_ID,IDX_CAT_PRD_IDX_PRICE_WS_ID_CSTR_GROUP_ID_MIN_PRICE | PRIMARY                                             | 8       | mage.cpf5.entity_id,const,const |     1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ref    | <auto_key3>                                                                                                                                              | <auto_key3>                                         | 5       | mage.ccf5.level                 |   113 | Using where                                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ncp        | ref    | export_id,category_id,product_id                                                                                                                         | export_id                                           | 4       | const                                  | 25002 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort       |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ccf5       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                  | PRIMARY                                             | 4       | mage.ncp.category_id            |     1 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is `group_id` indexed?

Comment: USE EXPLAIN before the SELECT to see what the optimizer says and which tables are using index. So you can optimize the query or the tables

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, it's created by this line: IFNULL(cpr.parent_id,cpf5.entity_id) AS `group_id`. So I don't think so.

Comment: I believe the order by is the heavy part, if you remove it how much time this query takes?(keep the group by)

Comment: Hi Bernd Buffen, see my updated question for the results. I'm not exactly sure what it says about the query and how to go from here.

Comment: Hi Sagi, I'm afraid it's not helping much... Only when I remove the GROUP BY and ORDER BY group_id it is much faster. If I leave one of them the query remains very slow. The ORDER BY type_id doesn't affect the speed.